# Best approach to Insert Data in Mysql through Laravel

Tags: laravel

Below are the two ways to insert data in MySql through laravel
**Way 1:**

```
$post = Post::create([
'title' => $request->input('title'),
'body' => $request->input('body')
]);
```

**Way 2:**

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->input('title');
$post->body = $request->input('body');
$post->save();
```

I just want to know which approach is better and why? Could anyone please tell which approach is better?

Answer (score 3):

`Model::create` is a simple wrapper around this, if you look at its implementation:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $model = new static($attributes);

    $model->save();

    return $model;
}
```

**save()**

`save()` method is used both for saving new model, and updating existing one. here you are creating new model or find existing one, setting its properties one by one and finally saves in database

`save()` accepts a full Eloquent model instance

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

$post = App\Post::find(1);`

$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

**create()**

while in `create` method you are passing array, setting properties in model and persists in database in one shot.

`create()` accepts a plain PHP array

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$comment = $post->comments()->create([
    'message' => 'A new comment.',
]);
```

Comment: I just want to know which approach is more preferable. Could you please specify this?

Comment: Create is more preferable because the things that he's saying, you can insert arrays and save in one shot.

Comment: If you see example I say preferably on my first example